# Left outer Join nao traz valores Nulos

Tags: mysql, query, select, join

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
formulario_campo ( cod_campo, descricao, cod_formulario )
```

Preenchidas com os seguintes valores

```
- input_nome, Nome, 1
- input_sexo, Sexo, 1
```

A segunda tabela:

```
— formulario_valor(cod_campo,valor,cd_oportunidade)
```

Nesta tabela fica os registros vinculados dos campos e seus respectivos valores, da seguinte maneira:

- input_nome, Fagner, 2
- input_sexo, M, 2

Para trazer os valores preenchidos da tabela `formulário_valor` eu faço um select principal na tabela `formulario_campo` e depois faço um `left outer join` na tabela `formulario_valor` para trazer o valor:

```
SELECT 
  a.`cod_campo`,
  a.`descricao`,
  b.valor,
  b.`cod_formulario`,
  b.`cod_oportunidade` 
FROM
  formulario_campo a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN formulario_valor b 
    ON (
      a.`cod_campo` = b.`cod_campo` 
      AND a.`cod_formulario` = b.`cod_formulario`
    ) 
WHERE b.cod_oportunidade = 145 
ORDER BY a.`ordem`
```

Esse select me trás o retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dúvida: adicionando novos campos na tabela formulario_campo, por exemplo agora adicionei um novo campo chamado: **input_data_nascimento**, logicamente este campo não possui valores registrados na tabela `formulario_valor`, o problema está sendo este ponto, o **select que estou fazendo acima não deveria me retornar todos os valores de campos que possuo registrados na tabela "formulario_campo"** e o registro **input_data_nascimento** vim com o valor de **NULL**?

Tentativas que fiz:

- **FULL OUTER JOIN**
- **LEFT OUTER JOIN**
- **RIGHT OUTER JOIN**
- **UNION**

Mas tudo isso não consegui trazer os campos novos que adiono com o valor null...

Comment: Tente colocar essa instrução `WHERE b.cod_oportunidade = 145 ` dentro do ON do LEFT JOIN. `and b.cod_oportunidade = 145 `. Deve resolver.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela ajuda, já tentei fazer da mesma maneira, mas não foi...

Comment: Não existe uma solução dinâmica pro que você quer. Você vai ter que ajustar no braço sempre que tiver um campo novo. Se é que eu entendi o seu problema.

Comment: Olá @DarkHyudrA agradeço novamente, porém o termo "não existe uma solução" está incorreto, uma solução existe sim, na nossa vida de desenvolvedor tudo é possível até o momento que pensamos, mas acredito que está faltando algo bem bobo nesse select, em resumo tenho uma tabela B que possui os valores cadastrados da tabela A, em determinado momento estou pegando todos os registros da tabela A e exibindo os valores da tabela B, porém quando adicionei um novo registro na tabela A que não existe na tabela B o select acima deveria me retornar a coluna Valor da tabela B como null, certo?

Comment: Uma pergunta: no select tem o campo novo?

Answer (score 2):

Cara está difícil entender seu problema, talvez você pudesse melhorar a descrição das suas tabelas e dados. Se eu compreendi corretamente, você não está vendo alguns dados por conta da cláusula 'Where'. Você deveria adicionar "OR b.cod_oportunidade IS NULL" para ter o resultado que eu entendi ser o esperado.

```
SELECT 
  a.cod_campo,
  a.descricao,
  b.valor,
  b.cod_formulario,
  b.cod_oportunidade 
FROM
  formulario_campo a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN formulario_valor b 
    ON (
      a.cod_campo = b.cod_campo 
      AND a.cod_formulario = b.cod_formulario
    ) 
WHERE b.cod_oportunidade = 145 OR b.cod_oportunidade IS NULL
ORDER BY a.ordem
```

Só uma dica: na cláusula 'ON' devemos colocar as **condições de junção** das tabelas e não os filtros que desejamos para a consulta. Os filtros devem vir na cláusula 'WHERE'

Comment: Olá Pedro, agradeço a resposta.. a Cláusula Where é necessário, na realidade este Select é apenas um resumo que fiz para ilustrar melhor, a cod_oportunidade nunca será nulla, ele é um codigo de um cliente. Mas em resumo o select que eu estou fazendo deveria me retornar mais um registro, na imagem que fiz na postagem ele me retornou aqueles registros que já existem na tabela de formulario_valor, porém inseri um novo registro na tabela formulario_campo e tecnicamente quando fizesse este select deveria me retornar este novo campo porem a coluna b.valor estaria como null.

Comment: @RoniSommerfeld, o código proposto pelo @PedroTeles está correto. Apesar de usar um **`left join`**, se você quer usar uma restrição na cláusula where na **tabela da direita** você precisa também contemplar a opossibilidade do registro vir nulo, senão o SGBD converte o seu `left join` para `inner join` implicitamente.